# Validation Rule for multiples columns

Tags: laravel-7, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm looking a solution for this.
I need make a validation to phone number, but for this I have 2 different columns in db, country_code (eg. 'us','br'..) and phone (row number...without +code). On create I need validate to no other user have the same country_code and phone at same time. For example

code: 'cu'
phone: 54363155

```
'phone' => ['phone:code',unique:App\Model\Customer],
'code' => ['required_with:phone']
```

In this case I can't create a Customer if the phone is registered in the db, but if that phone is valid for 'al' code must be validated and complete the creation function. How I must define that rule?

Comment: What is db? Is it a database? ArrayList? File?

Comment: I'm sorry, I must say table instead db. Inside customer table I have this two columns

Comment: Thatś all right, thanks for clarifying!